# sqlite database table is locked on tests

Tags: django, database, sqlite, testing

I am trying to migrate an application from django 1.11.1 to django 2.0.1
Tests are set up to run with sqlite in memory database. But every test is failing, because `sqlite3.OperationalError: database table is locked` for every table. How can I find out why is it locked? Icreasing timeout setting does not help.

I am using `LiveServerTestCase`, so I suppose the tests must be running in a different thread than the in memory database, and it for some reason does not get shared.

Comment: Any chance that your sqlite3 database is open in some IDE?

Comment: No. Tests running on wercker get same errors.

Comment: Are you running your tests in parallel?

Comment: How can I be sure that I am not? Even then, at least one of the tests should pass, or fail with a different message?

Comment: How do you run your tests? What is your TestRunner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hit this, too.  The `LiveServerTestCase` is multi-threaded since [this got merged](https://github.com/django/django/pull/7832).

It becomes a problem for me when my app under test issues multiple requests. Then, so my speculation, the LiveServer spawns threads to handle those requests. Those requests then  cause a write to the SQLite db. That in turn does not like multiple writing threads.

Funnily enough, `runserver` knows about `--nothreading`. But such an option seems to be missing for the test server.

The following snippet brought me a single-threaded test server:

```
class LiveServerSingleThread(LiveServerThread):
    """Runs a single threaded server rather than multi threaded. Reverts https://github.com/django/django/pull/7832"""

    def _create_server(self):

        """
        the keep-alive fixes introduced in Django 2.1.4 (934acf1126995f6e6ccba5947ec8f7561633c27f)
        cause problems when serving the static files in a stream.
        We disable the helper handle method that calls handle_one_request multiple times.
        """
        QuietWSGIRequestHandler.handle = QuietWSGIRequestHandler.handle_one_request

        return WSGIServer((self.host, self.port), QuietWSGIRequestHandler, allow_reuse_address=False)


class LiveServerSingleThreadedTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    "A thin sub-class which only sets the single-threaded server as a class"
    server_thread_class = LiveServerSingleThread
```

Then, derive your test class from `LiveServerSingleThreadedTestCase` instead of `LiveServerTestCase`.

Comment: In case you need it:
`from django.test.testcases import LiveServerThread, QuietWSGIRequestHandler`
`from django.core.servers.basehttp import WSGIServer`

Comment: This only causes the tests to timeout instead of raising the deadlock error.

Comment: For me this makes every request hang forever

Comment: yep. there were changes. But I have updated the snippet to reflect what we use to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

It was caused by [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29062#no2) django bug.

Answer (score 1):

Using a file-based database during testing fixes the "table is locked" error. To make Django use a file-based database, specify it's filename as test database name:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3.test'),
       },
    }
}
```

I suppose that the timeout setting is ignored in case of in-memory database, see this [comment for additional info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46831783/django-sqlite3-timeout-has-no-effect#comment87250584_46831783).

Comment: This negates much of the benefit of using an in-memory Sqlite database. Using a file massively slows down the database.